# Insert throw error : Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, linq

I am working in WPF application.

Following is the table schema which i am using :

[image]

In this table **file_name** is not a identity key and **ID** is identity column.

Following is the code i am using :

```
 t_table_name t = new t_table_name
                {
                    file_name = "test"
                };
                dc.t_table_names.InsertOnSubmit(t);
                dc.SubmitChanges();
```

**Error :**

```
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
 at Read_Object(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject item)
 at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item)
 at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
 at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
 at OMS.MyOrders.Model.MyOrderExecutor.SaveTransactions(List`1 changes)
 at OMS.MyOrders.Model.MyOrderExecutor.SavePartReceiving(List`1 source, String system)
```

I am not able to understand where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the solution for this. Actually problem was not in linq query, problem was in trigger which is fire on **t_table_name** insert. This trigger further calling a stored procedure which used to create file based on some conditions.

This is the output i got from stored procedure :

[image]

To solve this issue i am using Execute command as follow :

```
   dc.ExecuteCommand("Insert into t_table_name (file_name) values ({0})", "test3");
```

Now code is working fine :-)

Answer (score 3):

Did you set identity for primary key? If no, then you should set primary key manually...

Comment: what version of .net are you using?

Comment: I'm not able to create now a demo, but I can suggest to  check 100% that auto identity and regenerate dbml file. Because your code looks like workable.

Answer (score 0):

Identity of primary key needs to be set. Manually if not already.